# How to set author name for subversion when i'm using svn:keywords

Tags: svn, properties, version-control-keywords

I want to set my full name (or a name chosen by me) to appears in the $Id$ area on commit and not my nickname. Is there a way to do it?

OS: Ubuntu 8.10

Comment: Do you have access to hooks directory on the repository server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to set it :(

Comment: That's not true, you can set the property

Answer (score 3):

You want a file with your name on it and then

```
svn propset svn:keywords "Author" file.txt
```

As seen in http ://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

$Id$ is a combination of Revision Number, Date, Author and URL.

Comment: Sorry my english is not the best, i will try to explain my problem again:

When I use

svn propset svn:keywords "Id" file.txt

then i get something like:

$Id: tagging.phtml 3189 2009-05-31 13:33:58Z sirakov $

But I want  to put "firstname.lastname" (not my nickname "sirakov") every time when i commit someting new. 

I hope, you can now understand what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

You could, if the repository allows it, change the author. I would recommend not to do so though, because you'll have to do this after each commit.

Can't you just change your login name?

Comment: i can't change it, the nickname is generated automatically from my email, which i used to join the developer group.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have permissions to do this, [I'm told](http://www.tty1.net/blog/2008-07-01-svn-author-renaming_en.html) you can do it with the command

```
svn ps svn:author "author_name" --revprop -r revision_number "repository_url"
```

If you get an error, you'll need to [add pre/post propset hooks](http://home.introweb.nl/d/dodger/svnauthor.html).